# Understanding `get_combination_wise_output_matrix` when investigating a multi-label classification problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am currently working on a multi-label classification problem. I am using the [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml/index.html) library (further reading [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01460.pdf))

I understand that train / test split is important for these types of problems - ensuring label combinations are represented well in both (scikit-multilearn implements their own split method for this purpose).

My current goal is to understand how this works so that I can evaluate it properly - I am reading from [here](http://scikit.ml/stratification.html) primarily.

I am a little confused by the output of the `get_combination_wise_output_matrix` method. I understand at a high level it is giving me a breakdown of counts of label combinations for whatever order I specify.

Here is an example output I have observed:
[image]

The first question I have is does `(5, 5): 1,` mean anything other than the label at index 5 appears once, and this number is repeated for... *reasons?*

Additionally I haven't yet found any literature evaluating how / when to use different orders (my current approach to this is to qualitatively evaluate a few different options that seem reasonable given the specific problem I am trying (desperately) to solve

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `order` here means how many possible combinations of labels you want to compare (e.g., order=1 would by how often does each label appear, `order=2` would be how often any two combinations of labels appear with values like 5,5 meaning "rows that only have a label in index 5 and no other label, and where the max order should be the number of labels you have --> 23 in your case. If you set `order=23` and if you had a row that only had a label in index position 4, one of our results would be a vector of 4 repeated 23 times.

I think what's weird for me is that I would expect to see the "only one label in index 4" presented as `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ,,, 0, 0]` (== len 24) instead of `[4, 4, 4, ... 4, 4]` (== len 24).

Odd presentation for sure. Kind of like sparse matrix notation.